# Firestore - Web version 9 - get all documents in collection whose id is in array of ids

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to Firestore and trying to form a query to return all documents whose doc.id is in an array of ids.

So something like this:

```
const getAlbumSongs = async (songUids) => {
    let albumSongs = [];
    const q = query(collection(db, 'songs'), where('id', 'in', songUids));
    const snap = await getDocs(q);
    if (snap) {
      for (const doc of snap) {
        albumSongs.push({
          songId: doc.id,
          albumId: doc.data().album_id,
          authorId: doc.data().author_id,
          songTitle: doc.data().song_title,
          filePath: doc.data().file_path,
        });
      }
    }
    return albumSongs;
  };
```

I should note I'm calling the getAlbumSongs() function from within a getAlbums() function, like this:

```
  async function getAlbums() {
    setIsLoadingAlbums(true);
    const snap = await getDocs(collection(db, 'albums'));
    setIsLoadingAlbums(false);
    let albumsData = [];
    if (snap) {
      snap.forEach(async (doc) => {
        albumsData.push({
          ablumId: doc.id,
          albumTitle: doc.data().album_title,
          albumCoverUrl: doc.data().cover_url || 'https://picsum.photos/300',
          albumSongs: await getAlbumSongs(doc.data().song_uids), // this might be problematic?
        });
      });
      console.log('albumsData', albumsData);
      return albumsData;
    }
  }
```

Comment: So `songUids` is an array of ids, and you want to get all the documents where ID is one of any of the `songUids`?

Are you seeing any error messages with what you currently have?

Comment: @Nathan No error messages, but the snap consoles like this `Vh {_firestore: vc, _userDataWriter: nl, _snapshot: Nu, metadata: Rh, query: gc}`. I updated the question to show how I'm calling the function. I might have an nested async/await issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current code queries on a field called `id` in each document. If you want the **document** ID itself, that is part of the metadata of the document and you'll want to query on [`documentId()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#documentid) for that:

```
const q = query(collection(db, 'songs'), where(documentId(), 'in', songUids));
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice the field name OP was querying on ._. `documentId()` is a top-level function in V9 and seems it can't be used from FieldPath now .

Comment: Good point on the global name @Dharmaraj, I keep forgetting that. Updated my answer!

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen `documentId()` is unefined. Is it 'uid' mabye? or just 'id',

Comment: @KirkRoss did you import it from Firestore SDK? `import { documentId } from "firebase/firestore"`

Comment: @KirkRoss Any update here?

Comment: @Dharmaraj No I hadn't! lol. Thank you, this works. :)