# What are the best practices to check if a field that is linked to a user id in a collection is empty or not in firestore 9.18 & react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a users collection in which there are users based on ids, and each of them has a field called goal. I'd like to check if that goal field is empty or not in order to perform other actions/show other fields etc but I cannot figure out a way to do so.

What I am mostly confused about is the usage of the queries, I have found several different methods and none works, and I am not sure about all the updates and all.
I have the newest version of firebase, firestore and react.

My firebaseconfig:

```
    // v9 compat packages are API compatible with v8 code
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  ...
};

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);
export const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp);

export default firebaseApp;
```

An example of how I fetch data into a list:

```
const [goals, setGoals] = useState([]);

    const fetchPost = async () => {
       
        await getDocs(collection(db, "goals"))
            .then((querySnapshot)=>{               
                const newData = querySnapshot.docs
                    .map((doc) => ({...doc.data(), id:doc.id }));
                    setGoals(newData);                
                console.log(goals, newData);
            })
       
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchPost();

      }, []);
```

This is what I have now:

```
let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    var userEmail = user.email;
    let userName = userEmail.match(/^([^@]*)@/)[1];
    let userId = user.id;
    const [currentGoal, setCurrentGoal] = useState([]);
    const fetchPost = async () => {
       
        await getDocs(collection(db, "users"))
            .then((querySnapshot)=>{               
                const newData = querySnapshot.docs
                    .map((doc) => ({...doc.data(), id:doc.id }));
                    if(doc.id === userId )
                        setCurrentGoal(newData);
                            
                console.log(currentGoal, newData);
            })
       
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchPost();

      }, []);
```

But the problem is 1. the user id is not working (I don't know how to use it in a query) and I am unsure how to get the information about the goal field.
Here is my collection to make it more clear:
[image: collection]

I have tried these practices but didn't work:

- db.collection("users").where("email", "==", usersEmail)
  .get() ......
- the one tht starts with firestore(). ... -> it says firestore is not defined

Comment: You can use the condition on each document if it exists or not using `Object.hasOwnProperty('goal')` and `doc.data().goal !== ""` for exist or empty of goal field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object,hasOwnProperty("goal"))` and `doc.data().goal !== "")` to check if the goal property exist or is empty as follows:

```
import { query, collection, where, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { auth, db } from "./config/firebase";

export default function App() {
  const [currentGoal, setCurrentGoal] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPost = async () => {
      const user = auth.currentUser;
      const userId = user!.uid;

      const q = query(collection(db, "users"), where("id", "==", userId));

      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);

      const userData = querySnapshot.docs[0]?.data(); //getting the only user data

      if (userData.hasOwnProperty("goal") && userData.goal !== "") {
        const goal = userData.goal;
        setCurrentGoal(goal); //if goal exists and not empty set current goal
      } else {
        setCurrentGoal(""); //if goal not exists or empty set current goal as ""
      }
    };

    fetchPost();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Current goal: {currentGoal}</p>
      {/* other code here */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

As from the details you shared it looks like you are storing the goals just as a string field. Hence  why I have used currentGoal as a string property.

Reference : [**`Object.hasOwnProperty()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

Comment: This one worked. Thank you for writing the usage context. I was usure how to incorporate the other examples in a query. Also one thing I noticed, because of which it didn't work, was that I was trying to get the document id and had no user id anywhere within that, and the  code was checking that part, which was missing the user id itself so the code ran but got no result. But works now.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking how to query for the document ID in the v9 SDK, that'd be:

```
const qry = query(collection(db, "users"), where(documentId(), "==", "valuetosearchfor"));
const querySnapshot = getDocs(qry);
...
```

Also see my answer here: [Firestore - Web version 9 - get all documents in collection whose id is in array of ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72641240/firestore-web-version-9-get-all-documents-in-collection-whose-id-is-in-array)